# How do I correctly integrate AWS CodeDeploy with an AutoScaling group?

Tags: amazon-web-services, deployment, aws-code-deploy

I'm trying to figure out how to deploy my applications to my instances when a new instance is created by the Auto Scaling group, however the deployment doesn't seem to work what so ever and nothing I have tried seems to work.

---

I have created an Auto Scaling group which allows me to scale up and down when needed.

I have set up the relevant security groups needed for my applications. I have set up launch configurations.

I have created an application that is linked to the necessary application files in an S3 bucket and created an application deployment group which is linked to the Auto Scaling group.

When I scale the ASG to create a new instance manually, the instance gets created fine. However no code or applications are deployed onto the machine, and no logs are written in relation to CodeDeploy.

When I try to deploy the application manually, I always receive `The overall deployment failed because too many individual instances failed deployment, too few healthy instances are available for deployment, or some instances in your deployment group are experiencing problems. (Error code: HEALTH_CONSTRAINTS)` even though the health on my instance displays as Healthy

I have created two IAMs. Code deploy IAM is tied to the deployment group, and an EC2 IAM tied to each launched instance providing full access to CodeDeploy, EC2, S3.

CodeDeployIAM:
[image]

EC2 IAM:
[image]

**Question**

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong and how to get CodeDeploy functioning correctly?

---

I installed CodeDeploy on my instance and saved this as an AMI for the ASG to use and now it gets further. CodeDeploy downloads the files and I can see them deep inside one of the folders `/opt/codedeploy-agent/deployment-root/sha/d-L39JDN5MM/deployment-archive/`. The files are downloaded correctly here as expected, but they are not put into the correct file location using the `appspec.yml` and the deploy on AWS says Failed due to Health Constraints

---

**Edit 2**:

I think I've figured out my issue. My manual deploy takes the correct etag using `6cf236f11cd` but my autoscale deploy uses an outdated etag, and this doesn't exist anymore resulting in the error... How do I solve this?

In the logs I am seeing
`2017-12-20 21:58:08 ERROR [codedeploy-agent(3896)]: InstanceAgent::Plugins::CodeDeployPlugin::CommandPoller: Missing credentials - please check if this instance was started with an IAM instance profile` even though my instance was started with an IAM role

---

**Edit 3**:

It seems the credentials missing isn't an issue at the moment. My credential files are present with the correct data and the instance is launched with a valid IAM user. I can manually deploy to the instance and then once the manual deploy is done, it will fetch this every time it scales.

However, this doesn't work when I have a `AfterInstall` hook in my appspec.yml... Is there something wrong with the format?

`version: 0.0
os: linux
files:
   - source: /
     destination: /opt/lobby
hooks:
  AfterInstall:
    - location: scripts/bootstrap.sh
      timeout: 180`

---

**Edit 4:**

Found that the problem is my script not being executed at the end due to

```
2017-12-21 11:30:39 ERROR [codedeploy-agent(1285)]: InstanceAgent::Plugins::CodeDeployPlugin::CommandPoller: Error during perform: InstanceAgent::Plugins::CodeDeployPlugin::ScriptError - Script does not exist at specified location: /opt/codedeploy-agent/deployment-root/d74ccd1f-a398-4b43-9ee8-f5468b63bd8d/d-4L3N2ETIO/deployment-archive/opt/scripts/lobby-bootstrap.sh - /opt/codedeploy-agent/lib/instance_agent/plugins/codedeploy/hook_executor.rb:118:in `block (2 levels) in execute'
/opt/codedeploy-agent/lib/instance_agent/plugins/codedeploy/hook_executor.rb:116:in `each'
/opt/codedeploy-agent/lib/instance_agent/plugins/codedeploy/hook_executor.rb:116:in `block in execute'
/opt/codedeploy-agent/lib/instance_agent/plugins/codedeploy/hook_executor.rb:198:in `create_script_log_file_if_needed'
```

I have now embedded my script inside the deployment folder, but when the file gets deployed onto the machine in linux it is not executable so it can not be run. How can I run a pre-After Installation command to make this file executable?

```
2017-12-21 11:44:57 WARN  [codedeploy-agent(1285)]: InstanceAgent::Plugins::CodeDeployPlugin::HookExecutor: Script at specified location: bootstrap.sh is not executable.  Trying to make it executable.
```

Trying to read up on the appspec.yml format to add permissions as this seems to be the problem for now.

I am getting this error when trying to set permissions.

```
2017-12-21 12:00:19 ERROR [codedeploy-agent(1285)]: InstanceAgent::Plugins::CodeDeployPlugin::CommandPoller: Error during perform: Psych::SyntaxError - (<unknown>): mapping values are not allowed in this context at line 5 column 17 - /usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/psych.rb:377:in `parse'
```

---

**Edit 5:**

I have fixed my appspec.yml file and now my deploys are succeeding! However the applications are not being started as expected. I have a script that should start the applications but they are not running when the deployment has finished.

Where does the output of these scripts go (i.e. echo statements because they are not in the codedeploy log)

Perhaps my script is not being run at all. If my script file starts with `#!/bin/bash` then I get an error

```
deployment-archive/./bootstrap.sh: /bin/bash^M: bad interpreter: No such file or directory\\n\"}"}
```

But if I remove this first line, the deploy succeeds but it doesn't seem that the script gets run. This seems like dos2unix issue.

---

**Edit 6:**

After writing my bash/appspec file on a linux machine and packaging this up in my application, the deployment hangs and prints the warning in the console

```
WARN  [codedeploy-agent(1285)]: InstanceAgent::Plugins::CodeDeployPlugin::HookExecutor: Script at specified location: bootstrap.sh is not executable.  Trying to make it executable.
```

Eventually times out and displays deployment failed due to "HEALTH_CONSTRAINTS". Any more deployments after this does not print anything to the logs. Completely baffled.

**Does anyone know why CodeDeploy is hanging on the instances and getting stuck on this line????**